# Rearrange all strings in vector Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector, ranking

I have a large cell vector containing names of files in a directory using

`listing = dir(['foldername','\*.xlsx'])`.

The files have dates in the name but in a format which makes it difficult to determine order. For example each file is called dataDDMMYYY.xlsx where DDMMYYY are numbers representing the date of the data.

I want to get a vector of locations ranking the files from newest to oldest. One suggestion is to use `arrayfun` to remove "data" and "xlsx" from the the string and rearrange to YYYYMMDD using something like `new=[old(9:12), old(7:6), old(5:6)]`.
However I have not found combinations of these without errors.
Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at `regexp`, I am sure there is an regular expression that you can sue to extract this particular date format. You might even be able to find one online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the function `datenum` that outputs a number (smaller = older, bigger = newer) for each date, according to a specified format (in your case `ddmmyyyy`). Then you can use those numbers to sort the dates. This method assumes that all the files are either `.xls` or `.xlsx`, and their names begin with `data` before the actual date:

```
listing = dir(['fildername','\*.xls*']); % list all xls and xlsx files in directory
names = {listing.name}; % cell array with names only

[~,dates,~] = cellfun(@fileparts, names, 'uni', 0); % apply fileparts to every cell
dates = cell2mat(dates'); % convert to char matrix (all the string have to be equally long)
dates = dates(:,5:end); % remove 'data' from each string

new_dates = datenum(dates, 'ddmmyyyy'); % extract date number
[sorted_new_dates, index] = sort(new_dates, 'descend'); % sort from newest to oldest
```

Then you can use `index` to process your original files from newest to oldest.

```
listing(index).name % print sorted filenames :)
```

Comment: Thanks. Some folders do have a mix of xlsx and xls. How do you invoke fileparts without a loop?

Comment: Do we know for sure that every file starts with `data` right?

Comment: Yes. Only the extension differs

Comment: I edited the answer, this will work for xls and xlsx. You can use fileparts on every cell of a cell array by using `cellfun`. Hope this is what you were looking for! :)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!